# Using moviepy on AWS Lambda (Docker) throw segmentation fault error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, fastapi, moviepy

I am running fastapi on lambda and I got Lambda error which I believe related to moviepy and opencv. The error text is at the bottom.

My main.py (the part where the error is triggered)

```py
...
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
...
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8-x86_64

ADD app app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN yum -y install mesa-libGL libsndfile
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

ENV NUMBA_CACHE_DIR=/tmp
ENV MPLCONFIGDIR=/tmp

CMD ["app.main.handler"]
```

My requirements.txt

```
fastapi==0.89.1
librosa==0.9.2
mangum==0.15.1
mediapipe==0.8.9.1
moviepy==1.0.3
numpy==1.23.5
opencv-python-headless==4.6.0.66
pandas==1.2.1
pydub==0.25.1
Pyrebase4==4.5.0
requests==2.28.1
tensorflow==2.10.0
uvicorn[standard]==0.17.6
```

The error thrown on Lambda

```
RequestId: ba8f8500-8338-48c5-b908-8b8f546646f8 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault
Runtime.ExitError
```

The error thrown is not helpful at all so I'm having a hard time identifying the cause here. It's kinda weird because few months back, everything run perfectly. only recently the code is failing. What might be the solution for this?

Comment: "segmentation fault" is nothing to go on. please figure out how to get useful debugging information out of this system. AWS lambda surely provides for that?

Comment: That's the thing, the instance automatically killed before any error could be prompted.

Comment: IIRC you can try to run the image locally. Does this give any additional insight?

Comment: Yup you can and I did try. I tried running docker as it is (like if you want to deploy on a normal server) and running it as a Lambda docker. The first one works totally fine. The second one throws the same error as I mentioned.

Comment: Please confirm if you are getting this error on your local machine or on the aws lambda function

Comment: It throws error running in docker Lambda environment (in both local and AWS Lambda function)